# Load video entirely, so no partial loading occurs

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I've got a page, where I'm showing a video of around 7MB. I implemented a `canplaythrough` callback on the video. This seemed to work fine until i checked it out on someone's slow internet connection. What I'm actually doing is loading in one big video and skipping through the video to show different little parts of it.

But sometimes it then gets stuck halway and starts partial loading that part again. How can make sure the video is entirely preloaded and that browser won't reload any parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. How the video is buffered is not defined in the specifications and it's entirely up to the browser vendors how they implement the buffering mechanism.

The buffering takes into account things such as preload time, network speed but also tries to prevent downloading huge files to the user's computer that would take up unnecessary space on the disk.

That being said - some browsers do currently have some issues with their buffering mechanism such as the Chrome browser which doesn't always work as expected. If you're using Chrome then try with another browser to check how that behave with your code and scenario.